# Laravel , How are the params determined in api handler/controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to php and laravel.No experience in dynamically, loosely typed languages at all.
Writing REST API in Laravel/Php

in the api.php I create a route like this

```
Route::get('initMessages/{id}','ApiController@initMessages';
```

When the controller method is like this. Then id id passed  to the handler

```
public function initMessages($id)
{
    //$id is the same id passed in the url
    echo($id);       
    return response()->json(['result'=>'success'],200);
}
```

if the controller signature is like this

```
public function initMessages(ModelA $id)
{
    //Now id is an object of class ModelA
    echo($id);       
    return response()->json(['result'=>'success'],200);
}
```

if the controller signature is like this

```
public function initMessages(ModelB $id)
{
    //Now id is an object of ModelB
    echo($id);       
    return response()->json(['result'=>'success'],200);
}
```

Question :
How is this happening ?? What component in the code is determining the signature of method and passing the correct object ? What feature in the php language is being used to determine this ?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for Route Model Binding: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: To be short: PHP reflection + Di Service. That is when PHP [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php) feature comes in to introspect classes. And, of course, Di container (IoC). Laravel behind on the hoods introspects class methods and it knows which parameters e types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding).

The function is resolved using the Laravel container, which in turn will uses [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to determine the type of the function arguments.